What's this Label in Validation Rule?
I was looking at a Validation Rule and it has below text. I would like to know where this $Label is located in Object Manager?
CONTAINS($Label.List_of_users_and_profiles, $User.Id),
CONTAINS($Label.List_of_users_and_profiles, $Profile.Id)
CONTAINS($Label.List_of_profiles_to_skip, $Profile.Id),
NOT(CONTAINS($Label.List_Of_User_To_Skip, $User.Id

You'll find them in Setup | User Interface | Custom Labels. These are Custom Labels that can be used in the UI, formulas, and code (e.g. validation rules, Visualforce, Apex, Aura, etc), and are translatable in multi-language Salesforce orgs. Note that you will not find these in Object Manager, which only deals with objects, while $Label is a Global Variable.
